# Delete from three different tables with 1 query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to combine these three queries into one?

```
DELETE FROM `users exercises` WHERE `date` = '$date' AND `userid` = '$user->id'
DELETE FROM `users foods` WHERE `date` = '$date' AND `userid` = '$user->id'
DELETE FROM `users check-ins` WHERE `date` = '$date' AND `userid` = '$user->id'
```

Comment: Separating then with `;` only, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete from multiple tables if you can join them. That is true in your case. Try

```
DELETE e, f, c
FROM `users exercises` e
inner join `users foods` f on f.userid = e.userid and f.`date` = e.`date`
inner join `users check-ins` c on c.userid = e.userid and c.`date` = e.`date`
WHERE e.`date` = '$date' 
AND e.userid = '$user->id'
```